# Can I travel on F-1 visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I will have an F1 visa to study in the U.S, during my stay would I be able to enter Mexico for a vacation and return to the U.S on the same visa or would I need to obtain a travel visa as well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

A US visa allows you to seek admission to the US with a given immigration status.  To reenter the US in F-1 status after a trip abroad, you need a valid F-1 visa, not any other sort of visa.

(There's actually an exception called [automatic visa revalidation](https://help.cbp.gov/s/article/Article-1218?language=en_US) whereby you can use an expired visa to return to the US if you travel to Mexico or certain other nearby countries for 30 days or less, but in any event obtaining a regular tourist visa will not help you return to the US as an F-1 student; a tourist visa is only useful if you want to enter the US as a tourist.)